# jquery validation for more than min value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for form validation. Using the `min` property works fine, but I want it to validate values strictly *greater than* that min value.

```
rules: {
    price: {
        required: true,
        min: 13,
        number: true
    }
}
```

In my code I have `min: 13`, but I don't want to allow 13, only values greater than 13, e.g. 13.10, 13.20, 14. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Create your own custom method with [`$.validator.addMethod`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod):

```
$.validator.addMethod('minStrict', function (value, el, param) {
    return value > param;
});
```

Then use:

```
price: {
    required: true,
    minStrict: 13,
    number: true
}
```

---

**Note:** The creators of the validator plugin [recommend](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/min#value) adding `Number.MIN_VALUE` to the value you supply:

```
min: 13 + Number.MIN_VALUE
```

[`Number.MIN_VALUE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE) is the smallest positive (non-zero) float that JS can handle, hence the logic is that the two statements below are equivalent:

```
a > b;
a >= b + Number.MIN_VALUE;
```

**But**, this doesn't work, due to the way floating-point numbers are stored in memory. Rounding will cause `b + Number.MIN_VALUE` to equal `b` in most cases (`b` must be *very small* for this to work).

Comment: If someone needs to add a message as well to the validation like me, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352626/dynamic-jquery-validate-error-messages-with-addmethod-based-on-the-element

Comment: I was looking for `Number.MIN_VALUE`...  I didn't want to specify any value, just wanted it to be a positive non-zero number. You rock!

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Answer (score 1):

min: 13.01, this:

`rules:{
    price:{
        required: true,
        min: 13.01,
        number: true
    }
}`

Comment: It works. Just need to change validation message.