# jquery validation custom valdiator dynamic internailzed vlidator

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, jquery-validate

By using the jquery validation plugin, I try to write a **custom validator** with a **dynamic internalization support message**. ( The error message should be build dynamically and accept parameters in different locales.

For example we created a custom validator `amount` which always check the amount is bigger than zero:

```
$.validator.addMethod("amount", function(value, element,param) {
    var target = $(param);
    if (value)
        //The amount may have comma as thousand separator        
        return value.replace(/,/g,"") > 0;        
    else
        return this.optional(element);
}, "The amount should be more than zero");
```

To make it i18n support, we also added the translation different locales:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend($.validator.messages, {
        amount: "مبلغ میبایست بیشتر از صفر باشد" ,
    });
}(jQuery));
```

I found that we can make a message dynamic [Dynamic jQuery Validate error messages with AddMethod based on the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352626/dynamic-jquery-validate-error-messages-with-addmethod-based-on-the-element) but I don't know how to do it in other locales ?!