# Parameterize jQuery Validate Message based on element

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a jQuery-Validate rule called `dateTodayOrLater` which is applied to both an Element ID `editStartDate` and `editEndDate`. Depending on the field, I want my message formatted as `Start Time / End Time`.

I'm following the syntax where the message is the 2nd param after the method definition. However, the below isn't working, apparently because `$(element)` isn't available outside the function body. Any quick workarounds?

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("dateTodayOrLater", function(value, element, params) {                                       
    var momentValue = moment(value, 'MM/DD/YYYY', true);
    if (momentValue.isValid()) {
        var momentToday = moment().startOf('day');  // today without time
        if (momentValue.isSameOrAfter(momentToday)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        return true;
}, "The " + ( $(element).attr('id') == 'editStartDate' ? 'Start Date' : 'End Date') + 
   " must be the current date or a future date."); 
 // Note: The above Message param isn't working, "element" not available
```

Applied as

```
$("#editForm").validate({
    rules: {
        "startDate": {
            dateValid: true,
            dateTodayOrLater: true
        },
        "endDate": {
            dateValid: true,
            dateTodayOrLater: true
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: First, where is your HTML markup?  Rules are referenced by attribute `name`, not `id`.  Secondly, for your message to be constructed dynamically, you need it inside a function ->  `function(params, element){ return "The " + ( $(element).attr('id') == .... }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13352987/594235