# jQuery Validate Custom Function - More than Minimum Value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I was looking to do what this post describes:
[jquery validation for more than min value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302531/jquery-validation-for-more-than-min-value)

The only difference is that the field isn't required. Even if I modify the rules as listed below, it still reads the empty form field and refuses to validate. It only fails to validate when you submit the form. Any suggestions? Thanks much in advance.

```
$.validator.addMethod('minStrict', function (value, el, param) {
    return value > param;
});

rules: {
    price: {
        required: false,
        minStrict: 13,
        number: true
    }
}
```

Comment: If it fails to validate, you probably did something wrong in your HTML markup.  Please show the relevant HTML.     It would probably be a good idea to show the relevant parts of the `.validate()` method too, instead of just the `rules` object.  Do you have any JavaScript console errors?

Comment: Why `required: false`?  Just leave it out as not being required is the default.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if I leave `required:false` out. I'll post the HTML and `.validate()` method, too. But it validates just fine if I leave out the `minStrict` or if I change it to the built-in `min: xx`.

Comment: It's not supposed to make a difference if you leave out `required: false`; that's my point... it's the default.  Again, we need to see your HTML and the the `.validate()` method to see what you're trying to explain and determine what went wrong.

Comment: It might also help you to look at the default `min` function inside the plugin.  You will quickly see where yours is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing your code to the default `min` function from the plugin...

```
min: function( value, element, param ) {
    return this.optional(element) || value >= param;
}
```

Notice the OR `this.optional(element)`?  This part allows you to use the rule on an optional field.  Otherwise, your rule will make the field mandatory.

Until you show enough code to reproduce your problem, this works fine.  *(you also forgot to assign a validation message)*

```
$.validator.addMethod('minStrict', function (value, el, param) {
    return this.optional(el) || value > param;
}, "please enter more than {0}");
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/4ogdhp1f/](https://jsfiddle.net/4ogdhp1f/)

Comment: Sorry, I've been on the road a bunch for work and haven't been near a computer where I can pull the code for you. I appreciate your help and I'll take a look this weekend.

Comment: Adding `this.optional(element)` worked. Thanks much.